# Teradata covalent datatable row overflow

Tags: html, css, angular, datatable, teradata

I am writing angular 5 application and I am using Teradata components, but I have problem with DataTable.

here is picture of my table:
[image]

I would like to have description column on one line with "..." at the end, but setting **td-data-table-cell** don't work.

```
.td-data-table-cell {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

**SOLUTION:**

ok so I found out solution for this, maybe it will help someone

```
  <td-data-table
    #dataTable
    [data]="filteredData"
    [columns]="columns"
    [selectable]="true"
    [clickable]="true"
    [multiple]="true"
    [sortable]="true"
    [sortBy]="sortBy"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedRows"
    [sortOrder]="sortOrder"
    (sortChange)="sort($event)"
    (rowClick)="showAlert($event)"
    [style.height.px]="560"
    [style.minheight.px]="100">
      <ng-template tdDataTableTemplate="description" let-value="value" let-row="row" let-column="column">
        <p matTooltip="{{ row[column ]}}">{{ row[column] }}</p>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template tdDataTableTemplate="vendorName" let-value="value">
        <p matTooltip="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</p>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template tdDataTableTemplate="buttons" let-value="value">
        <button mat-button color="primary" color="primary" >text</button>
      </ng-template>
  </td-data-table>
```

with use of **ng-template** you can style specific columns.

and css for

```
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have to manipulate the styles for the covalent components css class (I believe its valid for the angular material as well) you need to add /deep/ keyword before the class name. This way it wont ignore the styles you are setting. 
Like this

> /deep/ .td-data-table-cell { text-overflow: ellipsis; }

Also if it shows an error on the /deep/ just ignore it and run it. It would run just fine.